# How can I list the taints on Kubernetes nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

The [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#taint) are great about explaining how to set a taint on a node, or remove one. And I can use `kubectl describe node` to get a verbose description of one node, including its taints. But what if I've forgotten the name of the taint I created, or which nodes I set it on? Can I list all of my nodes, with any taints that exist on them?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```bash
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec'
```

which will give the complete spec with node name, or:

```bash
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'
```

will produce the list of the taints per each node

Comment: or if you want the ip-xx.internal node name you can do:
`kubectl get nodes -o json | jq ".items[]|{name:.metadata.name, taints:.spec.taints}"`

Comment: this answer base on assumes that **jq** is installed.

Comment: And also just outputs a bunch of taints without outputting the name of the node they're associated with which isn't much use.

Answer (score 84):

The simplest way to do this without using any extra tools such as JQ is to use the custom-columns output option.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints --no-headers
```

Output:

```
master-11   [map[effect:PreferNoSchedule key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master]]
master-12   [map[effect:PreferNoSchedule key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master]]
master-13   [map[effect:PreferNoSchedule key:node-role.kubernetes.io/master]]
```

With something like Taints where it is a map or list and you want it to look clean for parsing with some other tool you can clean them up using  you can use something similar to the answer by Edwin Tai but with a little extra smarts to extract the keys.

```
kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.taints[*].key}{"\n"}{end}'
```

Output:

```
master-11   node-role.kubernetes.io/master
master-12   node-role.kubernetes.io/master
master-13   node-role.kubernetes.io/master
worker-21   thegoldfish.org/storage thegoldfish.org/compute
worker-22   thegoldfish.org/storage thegoldfish.org/compute
worker-23   thegoldfish.org/compute
worker-24   thegoldfish.org/storage thegoldfish.org/compute
```

#### Extra examples:

Using this method you can easily create custom outputs

Quick overview of nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,ARCH:.status.nodeInfo.architecture,KERNEL:.status.nodeInfo.kernelVersion,KUBLET:.status.nodeInfo.kubeletVersion,CPU:.status.capacity.cpu,RAM:.status.capacity.memory
```

Output:

```
NAME        ARCH    KERNEL                       KUBLET    CPU   RAM
master-11   amd64   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   v1.17.0   6     7910096Ki
master-12   amd64   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   v1.17.0   6     7910096Ki
master-13   amd64   3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64   v1.17.0   6     7910096Ki
```

Overview of pods and where to find them sorted by creation time:

```
kubectl get pods -A -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,NODE:.spec.nodeName,HOSTIP:.status.hostIP,PHASE:.status.phase,START_TIME:.metadata.creationTimestamp --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp
```

Output:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                                  NODE        HOSTIP            PHASE       START_TIME
kube-system            kube-proxy-rhmrz                                      master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:03Z
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-777v9                              master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:03Z
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-w7rch                              master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:03Z
kube-system            kube-scheduler-master-11                              master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:05Z
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-master-11                     master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:05Z
kube-system            etcd-master-11                                        master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:05Z
kube-system            kube-apiserver-master-11                              master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:22:05Z
kube-system            calico-node-sxls8                                     master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:55:41Z
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-6d85fdfbd8-dnpn4              master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T14:55:41Z
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-76585494d8-jx9cg            master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T16:10:16Z
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-5996555fd8-5z5p2                 master-11   192.168.121.108   Running     2019-12-26T16:10:16Z
```

The documentation for this is https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns

Answer (score 45):

In Kubernetes 1.6.x the node taints have moved into the spec. Therefore the above answer by jaxxstorm will not work. Instead, you can use the following template.

```gotemplate
{{printf "%-50s %-12s\n" "Node" "Taint"}}
{{- range .items}}
    {{- if $taint := (index .spec "taints") }}
        {{- .metadata.name }}{{ "\t" }}
        {{- range $taint }}
            {{- .key }}={{ .value }}:{{ .effect }}{{ "\t" }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- "\n" }}
    {{- end}}
{{- end}}
```

I have that saved into a file and then reference it like so:

```
kubectl get nodes -o go-template-file="./nodes-taints.tmpl"
```

You'll get output like so:

```
Node                                            Taint
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=etcd:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=jenkins:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=etcd:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=containerlinux-canary-channel-workers:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=jenkins:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=etcd:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=etcd:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=etcd:NoSchedule
ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal   dedicate=jenkins:NoSchedule
```

I'm not a huge go template user so I'm sure there are some things I could have done better but it is what it is.

---

Same as above but all in one line:

```
kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{printf "%-50s %-12s\n" "Node" "Taint"}}{{- range .items}}{{- if $taint := (index .spec "taints") }}{{- .metadata.name }}{{ "\t" }}{{- range $taint }}{{- .key }}={{ .value }}:{{ .effect }}{{ "\t" }}{{- end }}{{- "\n" }}{{- end}}{{- end}}'
```

Answer (score 21):

To find taints of node can just run:

```
kubectl describe nodes your-node-name
```

Output:

```
Name:                   your-node-name
...
Taints:                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 19 Jul 2017 06:00:23 +0800
```

Comment: this is handy when used with grep to filter out other information. `kubectl describe nodes your-node-name | grep Taints`

Answer (score 14):

```
#Check Node Taints
kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns=NodeName:.metadata.name,TaintKey:.spec.taints[*].key,TaintValue:.spec.taints[*].value,TaintEffect:.spec.taints[*].effect
```

Let me try and explain what this first one means and then rest should fall in place:

**NodeName:.metadata.name**

**ColumnName: JSONPATH to the attribute you are looking for.**

***ColumnName can be anything you want it to be.***

Something like **NodeName:items[*].metadata.name** is equivalent to running **$kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'** but with custom-columns flag you get values in rows and columns format.

**Note: You don't need to start with .items[*]. It already parses that with custom-column flag**

so now all the columns explained:

**NodeName:.metadata.name** - Get Node Names and put it under NodeName Column

**TaintKey:.spec.taints[*].key** - return all the keys for taints by looking under taints map and put it under TaintKey custom-column

**TaintValue:.spec.taints[*].value** - same as key but you are returning the value from the taints map.

**TaintEffect:.spec.taints[*].effect** - same as key but you are returning the effect from the taints map.

You set it under and alias like

```
alias get-nodetaints="kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns=NodeName:.metadata.name,TaintKey:.spec.taints[*].key,TaintValue:.spec.taints[*].value,TaintEffect:.spec.taints[*].effect"
```

and you have your own nice command to get all taints and your output should look something like below

[sample output for the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu1nD.png)

Comment: Hi Sandeep, great to give an actionable command, but maybe you can explain a little bit your command?

Comment: Hello @jeje - I hope the explanation help!

Answer (score 10):

Try this one:

```
    kubectl get nodes -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TAINTS:.spec.taints
```

Answer (score 4):

> PowerShell:\> kubectl describe nodes | findstr "Taint Hostname"

or

> Bash# kubectl describe nodes | egrep -hi "Taint|Hostname"

This command is mad easy to remember

Output looks like this:

```
Taints:             <none>  
  Hostname:   aks-agentpool-30208295-0  
Taints:             <none>    
  Hostname:  aks-agentpool-30208295-1
...
```

Here's another handy variation:

> Bash# kubectl describe nodes -l=cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=pool-1 | grep Taints -A 3

Comment: The syntax seems to be incorrect here - there is no line containing "Taint Hostname", so grep will not find anything. I think this should be `kubectl describe nodes | egrep "Taint|Hostname"`

Comment: Thanks your right, I only tested the powershell code, and made assumption that  Bash's grep would be similar but didn't test, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Version I use, which puts name first: `$ kubectl describe nodes | grep -E 'Name:|Taint'`

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to get the list of nodes that have a specific Taint. I only found this SO answer, so if anybody is looking for this answer, here is the solution:

```
kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{range $item := .items}}{{with $nodename := $item.metadata.name}}{{range $taint := $item.spec.taints}}{{if and (eq $taint.key "node-role.kubernetes.io/master") (eq $taint.effect "NoSchedule")}}{{printf "%s\n" $nodename}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

On my cluster, the output is:

```
preprod-master
preprod-proxy
```

Comment: This should be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kubectl`'s go-template output options to help you here,

`kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{if $x := index .metadata.annotations "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/taints"}}{{with $x := index .metadata.name}}{{.}}{{printf "\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'`

On my cluster, this prints my masters, which are tainted:

```
kubemaster-1.example.net
kubemaster-2.example.net
kubemaster-3.example.net
```

Comment: This no longer works in 1.6.x preparing a more complete answer for 1.6.x

Answer (score 2):

The CMD kubectl provides an arguments jsonpath to search and format the output after getting. You can check the doc [k8s jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) for detail.

```
 kubectl get node  -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.taints}{"\n"}{end}'
```

For further info, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/get/customcolumn.go#L239) that reflect the source data with the method FindResults

Comment: You did not convince me that this can help. Please explain how it works and how it solves the problem.

Comment: it provides an arguments jsonpath to search and format the output after getting. You can check the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/ for detail.

Comment: For further info, you can check the source code that reflect the source data with the method FindResults          https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/get/customcolumn.go#L239

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] your answer? Your comments would almost make a decent explanation, if they were not so close to link-only posts. I ask because the some ten of your answers I checked you never edited...

Answer (score 2):

Below commands worked for me:

1. If you have the node IP, You can try

```html
kubectl get node $node_ip -o json | jq '.spec.taints'
Output:
[
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "dedicated"
  }
]

(OR)

kubectl describe node $node_ip  | grep -i Taints
Output:
Taints:             dedicated:NoSchedule
```

2. To get all Taint config on namespace

```html
kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'
Output:
[
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "dedicated"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl describe nodes [node_name] | grep 'Taints'

kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'
```

--> this last step will require jq installed ( sudo apt install jq)

Answer (score 0):

kubectl describe node node01 | grep -i taints

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run below command:

```
kubectl describe node node_name | grep 'Taints'
```