# Kubernetes pods won't start even though node is a ready state

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, devops

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm struggling with starting my frist pods.
I installed kubernetes on my Ubuntu virtual machine, proceeded with

```
kubeadm init
```

followed by other instuctions

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

You should now deploy a pod network to the cluster.
Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/
```

I can see that the node is up and running

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
vm24740   Ready     master    12m       v1.10.0
```

Nevertheless my pods won't start:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-28jzj   0/1       Pending   0          11m
myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-9bbb9   0/1       Pending   0          11m
myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-fptft   0/1       Pending   0          11m
myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-lxj8p   0/1       Pending   0          11m
myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-xhg5f   0/1       Pending   0          11m
```

This is a detailed view on a pod:

```
kubectl describe pod myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-28jzj
Name:           myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4-28jzj
Namespace:      default
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=myapp
                pod-template-hash=1446748890
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/myappdeployment-588bc8ddf4
Containers:
  myapp:
    Image:        jamesquigley/exampleapp:v1.0.0
    Port:         9000/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-6rcjb (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  default-token-6rcjb:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-6rcjb
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  1m (x37 over 11m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Would somebody more experienced than me know, why the pods don't start?

Comment: As the Event said 0/1 nodes are available for scheduling: Your one node is tainted meaning pods can not be scheduled on it. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/  you can see current taints on node (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379415/how-can-i-list-the-taints-on-my-nodes) and removing them(https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints#removing_a_taint_from_a_node)  and then try launching again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seem like you are running single node (master) k8s:

From [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/):

> Master Isolation
>
> By default, your cluster will not schedule pods on
>   the master for security reasons. If you want to be able to schedule
>   pods on the master, e.g. for a single-machine Kubernetes cluster for
>   development, run:
>
> `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`
>
> With output looking something like:
>
> `node "test-01" untainted
>    taint key="dedicated" and effect="" not found.
>    taint key="dedicated" and effect="" not found`.
>
> This will remove `the node-role.kubernetes.io/master` taint from any nodes that have it,
>   including the master node, meaning that the scheduler will then be
>   able to schedule pods everywhere.

Comment: Generally you should at least bifurcate your cluster into master nodes and worker nodes. If one of your 'customer' pods runs amok it could starve the control plane components and effectively kill your cluster.