# NodeSelector can't find the label value in Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up a `Mongo DB`on a specific node on `GKE`. I upgraded my current cluster using

```
 gcloud container node-pools create mongo --cluster drogo --num-nodes 1 --region us-east1
```

It created a new node-pool in the cluster with the name `mongo`. I have the following `Deployment`, `Volume` and `Service` file.

## Deployment.YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:3.6.17-xenial
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mongo-pvc
```

In the above file, I provided the `nodeSelector` cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo (as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#deploy))

## Volume.YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

## Service.YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

When I check my pod error it says:

```
Can’t schedule this Pod because no nodes match the nodeSelector.
Cannot schedule pods: node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciable.

This is how I set up `Kubernetes Label` into a node pool

[image]

I ran  `gcloud container node-pools describe node  --cluster=drogo --region us-east1` and in the response I can see:

```
autoscaling: {}
config:
  diskSizeGb: 20
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS_CONTAINERD
  labels:
    mongo: mongo
  machineType: e2-medium
```

Comment: Could you also show us the labels and taints of your nodes? kubectl get nodes --show-labels and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379415/how-can-i-list-the-taints-on-kubernetes-nodes

Comment: @Yayotrón Check out the question description.

Comment: Change in your deployment's nodeSelector cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo for mongo: mongo

Comment: @Yayotrón I did not understand it correctly. You want me to replace `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo` to `mongo:mongo` ?

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly the label of your node has key mongo and value mongo, your nodeSelector should be mongo: mongo

Comment: @Yayotrón I tried it and it didn't work..Getting same error

Comment: I am getting `labels: mongo: mongo` when describing the`node`

Comment: Ok, the next part of your error is node(s) had volume node affinity conflict. This means that the volume you're trying to use cannot be used on the node you selected. A possible reason for this is that the volume is in a different availability zone. I can see that your node is in us-east-1, could you please find the persistent volume associated with this claim and the storage class and describe them both?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232946/discussion-between-yayotron-and-amit-pal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two issues with the deployment setup:

The `nodeSelector` specified in the Deployment manifest was using wrong label

```
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo
```

Whereas the created node had a label pair `mongo: mongo`. Either changing the node label to `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: mongo` or the deployment nodeSelector to `mongo: mongo` works.

The following issue was that the available `persistentVolume` lived in AZ `us-east1-c` whereas the available node was in `us-east1-d`. Therefore kubernetes scheduler couldn't find a match of requested `nodeSelector` + `PersistentVolume` within the same AZ. Issue was solved by adding a new node with the same configuration in AZ `us-east1-c`